# I want params from react router 3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get the value of `flavor`, whatever that may be, and have it available to my `Candy` React component.

**Routes**

```
export default function createRoutes() {
    return (
        <Route component={App}>
            <Route path="/"                 getComponent={requireAsync('Home')}/>
            <Route path="/candy/:flavor"    getComponent={requireAsync('Candy')}/>
            <Route path="*"                 getComponent={requireAsync('NotFound')}/>
        </Route>
    )
}
```

**Candy Component**

```
class Candy extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.match.flavor}</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

**What I'm Expecting:**

I want `localhost/candy/chocolate` to show a page with `chocolate`

Or `localhost/candy/vanilla` to show a page with `vanilla`

Or any parameter I want!

**My Environment:**

I'm using an isomorphic javascript stack. I want to be able to use `getComponent` to asynchronously load my pages. I know if I do this with just React, it will work fine, but I just don't know how to get the route params in a isomorphic JS stack.

- React 15.6.x+
- React Router 3.0.5 (`getComponent` is deprecated in 4, so I'm using 3)

Comment: `this.props.params.flavor`. match is for v4

Comment: How do I get the `params` for V3? I'm meticulously looking through GitHub docs for V3 but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: just the way I wrote it. `this.props.params.flavor`

Comment: if that doesn't work then maybe `requireAsync` isn't passing props properly

Comment: torontojs has a popular slack where you can get questions answered quickly, if you're not already there. http://slack.torontojs.com/

Comment: azium thank you so much, that did it! You've helped me solved my issue!